# Java Compilation date, like C __DATE__

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I need to automate getting the compilation date in a specific format into one Java Source file, like the C compilers **DATE** define, How?

Comment: Version control.  Need to know from the jar file when it was built.

Comment: In that case do consider putting it into the jar manifest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard Java compiler has no way of doing this (I don't think C compilers do either - I'm guessing that it is the pre-processor that gives DATE, FILE etc)

You'll have to write a source file with the date as a string into it - look at ant's copy task with a filter

```
<copy file="pre-src/Version.java" toFile="src/Version.java">
  <filterset>
    <filter token="DATE" value="${TODAY}"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

then in your source

```
public class Version {
    public static final String date = "@DATE@";
}
```

To get the date in various formats into the ant property TODAY look at the Tstamp task.

Comment: You need to call the <tstamp/> task before using ${TODAY}. Otherwise, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using aspectj compile time weaving to initialise a variable (you would obviously want to do the assignment by converting the date in your aspect to a string and then have your code parse that string).

Of course there is also nothing stopping you actually using a c pre-processor on a java file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered annotation processors? You can run them before compilation with javac and then manually add date to the file if there was certain annotation.